# Merge replication changing rowguid

Tags: sql-server, replication, merge-replication

We have a diversified environment. It is composed by 194 publishers and the total of 209 subscriptions.

The publisher and distributor both are SQL Server 2008 R2.

As subscribers we have 2008 R2 (different versions and sps) and 2000 (different versions and sps).

We separated the total of tables in some publishers to be more organized.

We insert the row at subscriber, and somehow it shows at publisher with exactly the same values and pks, but with different rowguid. The gen_status is always 1, saying that the row is created there, but it isn't. On Merge replication, it happens a lot with us.

We searched all over web and didn't find out what the problem is.